Page Item not passing value to PL/SQL Dynamic Content Region in Oracle APEX
I need help with PL/SQL Dynamic Content Region.
Based on selection in page item (on item change event) dynamic content region should be refreshed to show all images based on selected value images in page item. PL/SQL generates html slider:
declare
    is_first boolean := true;
begin
    sys.htp.p('<html>');
    sys.htp.p('<head>');
    sys.htp.p('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
    sys.htp.p('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>');
    sys.htp.p('<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>');
    sys.htp.p('<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>');
    sys.htp.p('</head>');
    sys.htp.p('<body>');
    sys.htp.p(:P23_CAR_ID);
    sys.htp.p('<div id="simple_carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">');
    sys.htp.p('<div class="carousel-inner">');
    
    for a in (select car_image_id
        from car_images
        where car_id = :P23_SELECT) loop
        if is_first then
            sys.htp.p('<div class="carousel-item active">');
            is_first := false;
        else
            sys.htp.p('<div class="carousel-item">');
        end if;
        sys.htp.p('<img src="https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/appname/images/cars/' || (a.car_image_id) || '" class="d-block w-100" alt="Image ' || apex_escape.html(a.car_image_id) || '">');
        sys.htp.p('</div>');
    end loop;
    
    sys.htp.p('</div>');
    sys.htp.p('<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#simple_carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">');
    sys.htp.p('<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
    sys.htp.p('<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>');
    sys.htp.p('</a>');
    sys.htp.p('<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#simple_carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">');
    sys.htp.p('<span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>');
    sys.htp.p('<span class="sr-only">Next</span>');
    sys.htp.p('</a>');
    sys.htp.p('</div>');
    sys.htp.p('</body>');
    sys.htp.p('</html>');
end;


Page loads without errors, after change of item value (which is LOV), following error, that has no much sense appears:
Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
If I set page item session state storage to "Session (Persistent)", after page reload, it shows slider just fine, with all images.
Also, If I hardcode car_id in sql, it shows slider in initial page load as it should, therefore my conclusion is that something is not synchronized correctly.
Dynamic action configuration and order:
On item change (P23_Select), True action: Refresh PL\SQL Dynamic Content Region.
fire on initialization is disabled.
I tried to add new page item, that will capture if first item change is handled properly, so I set value based on first item change, and it works as expected, second item get value after change of first one correctly, but for some reason, it does not work properly for the region.
I am not sure if makes sense to try to create a function in DB and just call it in region.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Kind Regards,
Strahinja

Are you using an APEX version that supports refresh of dynamic PL/SQL regions?

Also, have you considered the carousel component? https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/apex_pm/ut/carousel-region

To pick up the session state of a page item in a region on refresh, the page item needs to be be set in the "Page Items to submit" attribute of the region. For dynamic content regions, support for partial page refresh has been added a couple of versions ago. So... depending on the version you're on, it might or might not be possible to do a partial page refresh.

Hi all, tnx for responses.
I am using latest version available, since I am on cloud, not on local machine.
I've tried adding item in "Page Items to Submit", but it doesn't work anyway.
I will check out carousel component, but this solution, if worked, would be perfect match for my case.
@Scott

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@KoenLostrie

When instead of "Refresh" action region, in true branch I select "Submit Page", it works fine.
